# Mapping a Complex Entity using MapStruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I would like to map a string coming from a request object provided in the body of a request from user to a record in the database. The idea is I have a Product entity and the Product can have variations on it. I have a separate table for product variations and also a table for variation types such as color, size, shoe_size... I want the user, when creating a Product through the API to simply pass the variation type and the value so basically something like this

```
{
    "name": "Cool Green Sneakers, Size 10", // Name of product
    "description": "These are cool sneakers!", 
    ... // other product attributes
    "variations": [
        {
           "name": "size", // refers to variation name that must exist in Variation table
           "value": "10"
        },
        {
           "name": "color" // again, must exist in variation table
           "value": "Green"
        }
    ]
}
```

So this request body the client sends is a DTO that I need to convert to an actual Product entity object. I am using MapStruct to convert the ProductDTO to Product and I want to somehow map the name given for each variation in the variations list above to the existing Variation record that corresponds to the variation name and to throw some kind of exception if the variation name does not exist in the Variation table. Is there a way to do this in mapstruct? I know it's a bit complex which is why I'm currently doing this super manually but thought it would be great to clean up my code a bit.

Below are my entity classes for ProductItem, Variation and VariationOption. Variation is the variation type i.e. color, size, fabric... and then VariationOption relates a variation value to variation type i.e. green,red,blue relate to Variation of color in Variation table and SM,MD,LG,XL relate to variation type of size in Variation table

```
/* This is an instance of the product
For instance product can be slim t-shirt
and product item can be slim t-shirt in size Medium and color Black
* */
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="product_items")
public class ProductItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    // product is simply the parent product while product items are the variations of the parent product
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    // standard identifier in e-commerce world
    private String sku;
    private int quantityInStock;

    private String productImage;
    private BigDecimal price;
    // the variation options this relates to
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="product_configuration",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="variation_option_id"))
    private List<VariationOption> variationOptions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="variations")
public class Variation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // A variation such as sneaker size belongs to sneaker category. All subcategories of sneakers will then have shoeSize variation
    @OneToOne
    private Category category;

}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Builder
@Table(name="variation_options")
public class VariationOption {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Variation variation;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "variationOptions")
    private List<ProductItem> productItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setVariation(Variation variation) {
        this.variation = variation;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addProductItem(ProductItem productItem) {
        productItems.add(productItem);
    }
    public void removeProductItem(ProductItem productItem) {
        productItems.remove(productItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is already done by SpringBoot By default. Spring uses Jackson in REST Controllers to map request bodiesto Java Object. Mapstruct is used for mapping java object to other java objects.